# Docker images and the kernel

Tags: kernel, docker

have just spun up a docker image which is running Ubuntu 15.10 on my own machine which is still on 14.04. From what I have read, docker containers use your existing systems services, including the kernel.

How can a docker image which contains the latest version of an OS run on a machine running a version of the same OS, albeit 3 major versions behind and yet still use the same kernel?

Is the kernel a separate thing from linux OS images? And if so, are there really no issues from running different major versions of kernels (i.e. 3 -> 4) on the same OS version? I would have imagined backward compatibility issues as well as 'missing features'

Answer (score 0):

generally, the kernel ABI for userspace does not change between kernel versions, so user space tools compiled against newer kernel versions will be able to run on older kernel versions.